# accessing the value of a checked input in a json generated table

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a table produced by a getJSON ajax call and I want to loop through and collect the checked values and put them into a database.

The table looks like this:

```
<div class="content">
<table>
<tr> <td> etc. </td> </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

The content div exists but the table, the rows and cells are created by the ajax script so:

```
$.each( data, function( key, value ) {
        var txt =  '<tr>';
            txt += '<td style=\"background:#E3F6CE;\"><input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"case\" value=\"' + this["id"] + '\">';
            txt += '<td><a href=\"/edit/' + this["id"] + '\">'+ this["first"] + ' ' + this["last"]  + '</a></td>';
            txt += '<td>' + this["designation"] + '</td>';
        txt += '<td>' + this["company"] + '</td>';
            txt += '<td>' + this["email"] + '</td>';
            txt += '<td>' + this["remarks"] + '</td>';
        txt += '</tr>';
            $('.content').append(txt);
        });
```

So far so good, no problems. The table renders fine.

Now, the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".content").on( "input:checked" ).each(function() {
     //var id = $(this).val();
        var id = $( "input:checked" ).val();
              alert(id);
  });
});
```

only grabs one id, so if multiple checkboxes are checked it only gets one, not all.

What's going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-in-an-array-how-to-do-that-in-javascript

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: Try my answer it will give you all the checked checkboxes value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an array for that try like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".add").on("click",function(){
        var chk_vals = [];
        $("input:checked").each(function() {
             var id = $(this).val();
             console.log(id); // use this to check each checkbox value in console
             chk_vals.push(id);  
        });
    console.log(chk_vals); // use this to check the result in console.
    });

});
```

Comment: thanks DH, same result only gets 1 (of multiple) ids!

Comment: Maurice, I am trying to collect the ids of all the checked checkboxes and then, via ajax, put them into a database

Comment: url is here: http://richtalent.herokuapp.com/cuse  1) select industry,2 select country 3) "go" 4) seelct shortlist then check checkboxes then click "add". All the ids of selected people should then go to DB with the id of the relevant shortlist they are added to.

Comment: @user1903663 try to console.log(id) inside the each function. tell me is it giving all the ids.?

Comment: @user1903663 try my updated answer. and tell me is it working or not. also i will check on the same url that you have given.

Comment: @user1903663 one more thing add attribute name="YOUR CHECKBOX NAME" for each checkbox.

Comment: still 1. I think the problem lies with $(.each and delegation (on or live)

Comment: @user1903663 Try to use live click event but make sure .live is deprecated from jquery 1.9 so you have to use previous version of jquery.

Comment: I am using on not live

Comment: got to the url above and take a look and view source

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39113/discussion-between-dh-and-user1903663)